# grunt-processhtml Defining a variable number of files

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I'm using [grunt-processhtml](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-processhtml) to replace a few things before things go to production. The trick is, I have a variable number of files that are spat out by [assemble](http://assemble.io), and I really want to keep my data separate from my gruntfile. It would seem I have to do something to declare each file that needs manipulation:

```
    processhtml: {
      deploy: {
        options: {
          process: true,
        },
        files: {
          '/one_file.html': ['/one_file.html'],
          '/two_file.html': ['/two_file.html'],
          '/red_file.html': ['/red_file.html'],
          '/blue_file.html': ['/blue_file.html']
        }
      }
    }
```

As you can imagine, that could get quite cumbersome.

I know that with most grunt specific node modules, you can use some [globbing techniques](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), so I tinkered with that.

```
    processhtml: {
      deploy: {
        options: {
          process: true,
        },
        files: {
          '/**.html': ['/**.html']
        }
      }
    },
```

But that doesn't seem to work either... Any suggestions?

## Edit: Add More Background Information (In case I'm losing the forest for the trees)

### The Problems

I have a few major goals for my development environment.

- Viewing pages locally with non-compressed files for debugging (this goes for html, css, and js)
- The ability to work completely offline as I travel, and am often without internet. This can also have the side effect of making page reloads even faster. A few things that I've encountered as problems with this, and why I came to processhtml:

  - Using CDNs to serve up things like jQuery.
  - Google fonts: If I reference a google font, it generates the CSS on the spot, based on my browser... but since I have my fonts that I'm developing with installed locally, I just want to use those, so I need a way of keeping the google fonts inserted.
- I want to be able to compress and concatenate every single asset before deployment.

### How I'm Going About It (for better or worse)

So, now I'll tell you about the system I've devised. I have three top level directories in my project where the three different phases live

1. src: this is where all of my assemble files live. Within here, I have tons of hbs files, and partials, thus keeping my markup dry, and my minimal data in YAML (which I love, as I can have coworkers fill it out).
2. dev: once the files are "assembled" they end up in this directory. Here they are uncompressed, and the connect server with livereload is run from here.
3. deploy: At this point, I have a grunt task called 'preflight' which compresses all of my files down, and gets rid of any cruft, leaving a super sleek streamlined folder ready for another rsync task to send it up to production.

Anyway, if you have a different way to accomplish this. I would love to hear it :)

Thanks!

Comment: If you could share more with us about what you're trying to accomplish on the Assemble issues we might have an easier solution that doesn't require another task to be used.

Comment: Great point! I was wondering that as well. I will edit my question to include a bit more background.

Comment: Great, thanks for the additional info. So the grunt-processhtml task is being used to replace references to non-minified assets (which might be multiple link or script tags) with references to minified assets (in which case multiple link tags would be replaced with one). is that the gist?

Comment: That's correct. Though I think it might be important to point out that I'm also using it to replace some references to things offline (particularly google fonts) with the ones that are online for deployment. 
One simple way to do it, would be to just have the replacement take place in the partials that generate all of the files, but that would create problems when trying to work offline.

Comment: thanks for the additional detail, let me think about this, I think @doowb and I can come up with something :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After writing a method to accomplish the task, and then some further checking the manual, I found this:

http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically

My Gruntfile config contains something that looks like this, and it works like a charm:

```
    processhtml: {
      deploy:{
        options: {
          process: true,
        },
        files: [
          {
          expand: true,     
          cwd: 'deploy/',   
          src: ['**/*.html'],
          dest: 'deploy/',  
          ext: '.html'
        },
        ],
    }
```

Comment: The Grunt documentation about file handling is very poor imo. The key note on this answer is `expand: true`. This will take the src expression, determine a path for each file, and set the destination path _relative_ to the dest. If destination is not specified, then the files will be updated/replaced in place.

Comment: how to you exclude a specific folder? my folder to exclude is "_includes" and i would like to add this exclusion with the configuration of this answer

Answer (score 1):

counterbeing's solution works like a charm!

@valerio0999
to exclude a folder use the '!' negation operator on the 'src'

```
processhtml: {
  deploy:{
    options: {
      process: true,
    },
    files: [
      {
      expand: true,     
      cwd: 'deploy/',   
      src: ['**/*.html', '!**/_includes/**'],
      dest: 'deploy/',  
      ext: '.html'
    },
    ],
}
```